# RabbitMQ redelivery backoff of rejected requeued messages?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a simple service that subscribes to messages from RabbitMQ and writes them down to a datastore. Sometimes this datastore is unavailable for some short periods of time (sometimes seconds but sometimes minutes). If this happens we do a `basic.reject` on the failed message with `requeue` set to `true`. While this works the message seems to get redelivered immediately. I'd like RabbitMQ to gracefully backoff the redelivery. For example first try to redeliver "immediately" then after 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 seconds etc. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: You can have a check at : http://globaldev.co.uk/2014/07/back-off-and-retry-with-rabbitmq/. Basically the idea is to set a ttl per message !

Comment: @LouisF. you deleted your post here http://stackoverflow.com/q/35399063/4828463 Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in addition to what Louis F. posted as a commented, check out the Delayed Message Exchange plugin https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/

You could set up a dead-letter exchange using the delayed message exchange type, and have this very easily accomplished without having to do a bunch of configuration and use TTLs like that.

Comment: Thanks for this, seems much cleaner than the DLX + TTL hack I've ben using.