# How to pull specific data from an object in an arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Ok, not sure if the title worded that correctly but say I have three objects with two strings of data each(Lets say a stateName and a cityName) stored into an arraylist. Is it possible to enter in a state name in as a string variable(call it searchStateName), then have a method search through the objects in the list and compare searchStateName to the stateName inside each object in the arraylist, and when a match is found have it return the cityName that is inside the same object as the matching stateName?

I am trying to do something similar currently and would like to figure it out myself, but I have been working on this for the past hour and am completely lost. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have tried?

Comment: First of all, you are not using an ArrayList. You are using arrays. Second, your method is not returning a String (city name should be a String). It is returning a boolean means true or false. Your code is still not clear. Can you post everything?

Comment: It is not a problem we can you arrays as well. But I would like to see where you added state names and city names to the array. And that contains method is not clear to me. If you can post all the code you have, I will be able to help more easily. After all how big could you code be. You are just starting out with java.

Comment: @FarazDurrani Overall, my program is using 5 different classes, with 100's of code per class, so I am trying to post the methods I am using in each in a way that they would work in a single class. This is just a small piece of a program I am having to make. The last piece actually, and it's extremely frustrating that I can't figure this out. I am not sure if you can PM on here, but if you are willing I could send everything I am working with through that so you can help me figure it out.

Comment: @Chichi230 This code is screwed up lol. I don't understand why are you passing a instance of List class inside displayCity(List myList) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach. Say you have a class called `SC` and you have two instance variables in it and getters and setters for them. You need to initialize 3 objects of them inside your main:

```
SC a = new SC("Illinois ","Chicago ");
SC b = new SC("Michigan ","Detroit");
SC c = new SC("New York"," New York");
```

And then create an `ArrayList` of object `SC` and add those 3 objects of `SC` to that ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<SC> list = new ArrayList<SC>();
list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
```

Now call the method that search for a state name and returns the city name if it finds it:

```
this.searchStateName("Illinois");
```

The actual implementation of this method with `for-each` loop:

```
public String searchStateName(String stateName){
 String result = "No city found.";
      for (SC sc : list )
         if (sc.getStateName().equalsIgnoreCase(stateName)){
          result = sc.getCityName();
          break;
        }
    }
 return result;
}
```

If you are not comfortable with `for-each` loop then you can use the regular `for` loop below. I commented out on purpose. But it will work correctly and give you the correct city name.

```
//public String searchStateName(String stateName){
// String result = null;
//      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
//         if (list.get(i).getStateName() .equalsIgnoreCase(stateName)){
//          result = list.get(i).getCityName();
//          break;
//        }
//    }
// return result;
//}
```

And thats it. Let me know if you need help further.

Comment: Ok, I follow your code and understand it up until this line "getStateName.equalsequalsIgnoreCase(stateName)"          What does this mean? Also, I did not downvote you.

Comment: ok let me explain. list has 3 objects in it (you did that when you added them to list (list.add(a), list.add(b), ...). So you want to go through each object, and get the state name out of each object, and then match it with the statename that you sent via method parameter, and evaluate if they are the same

Comment: so when i = 0; the first indice can be extracted by list.get(i). Then after getting to first object, you want to extract out the state name, so list.get(i).getStateName(). Then use the Strings built in method called equalsequalsIgnoreCase and provide the stateName to that method: ....equalsequalsIgnoreCase(statename).

Comment: And then go though all 3 objects until you find the state that you desire, and when thats true, go inside the if statement and extract the city name  and assign it to result. And when the for-loop ends, return the result

Comment: Oh!!!! maybe you got confused that where did getStateName() method come from? Thats a getter method inside SC class. Do you know about POJOs and getters and setters?

Comment: One should not use for loop, but instead foreach loop. Cf Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 46

Comment: I would remove it yes ! Also note that your solution is not correct since it can return null. I would change it to return an Optional of String

Comment: Ok, I have a problem with this, I can't get it to work. My list is in another class file initiated as an object (private Object[] entry;) I am using a different class file to enter in the name to search, then calling a method inside the class with the list in it, to return a boolean back to my main class file. Is there a way to implement what you shown me using that? I will edit my main post to show the code I am working with.

Comment: @FarazDurrani I added the code I am having to work with. If that is enough. Sorry if I am being incompetent here, I am pretty new to coding, just now going through a second semester in college.

Comment: Okay, quit being so desperate for an upvote, the community is to help, not an endless grind for points. And, by the way, I have made the appropriate changes to your answer.